# How can I catch an Exception triggered by databound Control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, exception

I have a databound [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx)-Control, bound like this:

```
Binding b = new Binding("Value", myDataSource, "myProperty");
b.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
numericUpDown.DataBindings.Add(b);
```

Changing `myProperty` has some further effects and might throw an exception somewhere further down.

Some of the information needed to check if the Exception will be thrown is not available in the GUI, so validating the input is difficult. 
Can I catch the exception triggered by the value change my DataBinding makes? Or is this a bad Design? If so, should I rather make all necessary information available to be able to validate the input correctly, or should I not use DataBinding for making complex changes?

I would greatly appreciate any help!

richn

Comment: As you suggested, DataBinding should not be against complex properties. Validation should be done when retrieving and setting the property.

Comment: Thank you John. I would accept this as an answer if you wrote one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Databinding should not be against complex properties.

Validation should be done when retrieving and setting the property.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion. Binding against "complex" properties (i.e. UDT's or enums) is very useful for reducing amount of boilerplate code.

Comment: You misunderstand the question and it's underlying problem.  A complex property would be one with large calculations and routines that could generate an exception during databinding.  This should be avoided - and has nothing to do with the TYPE of the property itself.

Comment: That may be, however numeric up/down the author is talking about is not all that complex.

Comment: I'll risk one last response to keep future readers clear. The question asked about binding a custom 'myProperty' which the author specifically asked how to handle exceptions in that custom property. Answer: Do not have custom properties complex enough to require thrown exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

When a binding value change causes the exception, you will find that sometimes the binding swallows it up.

To get at it, you can hook onto the binding's [`BindingComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.bindingcomplete.aspx) event (you might need to set the binding to have `FormattingEnabled` to true as well). At that point, any exceptions caught while the binding is writing to the datasource will be bubbled out on the event args (on it's [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcompleteeventargs.exception.aspx) property). The catch is that unfortunately you'll probably find that the bulk of the stack trace is lost...

**EDIT**: If you are using a BindingSource component, it also bubbles `BindingComplete` events. So that might be a quicker way to capture exceptions thrown by other bindings as well.